# Visual Studio 2012 unable to find my tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have added a "Unit Test Library" project to my solution containing a simple test class:

```
namespace Metro_test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.Equals(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to make the test show up in the text explorer window. I have tried cleaning/rebuilding the solution, removing/re-adding references to MSTest and editing the .csproj file to make sure the project is marked as a test-project.

The whole solution is under source control and my colleague (working with the same code) is having no problem running the test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure processor architecture is same in test menu and solution

Comment: @HarisHasan Everything is set as x86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, which can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

Then also make sure that you are using the assemblies that you added reference to.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

and remove the old

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;
```

**EDIT**

You could also just update your visual studio to update 3, which should solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I got into same issue when upgrading solution from VS 2010 to 2012. All tests disapeared.
I got over this by deleting the old (VS2010) solution file.
Then, I created new one using VS2012 and added all the projects to the new solution.
After Rebuild all tests appeared in tests explorer.