# Why is Visual Studio's Test Explorer not finding this test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Given two projects loaded into Visual Studio, one named MyCo.Storage and a second named MyCo.Storage.Testing which performs "black box testing" on the first, the tests from MyCo.Storage.Testing are no showing up in the Test Explorer. Noteworthy details are:

1. Tests in MyCo.Storage do appear in the test explorer.
2. Creating a new "Unit test project" contains tests that work (when all setting except the project name are the same).
3. Running code analysis on MyCo.Storage.Testing produces and error about being unable to load a type from MyCo.Storage.

All the answers from:

[Why does visual studio 2012 not find my tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533259/why-does-visual-studio-2012-not-find-my-tests) and
[Visual Studio 2012 unable to find my tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074509/visual-studio-2012-unable-to-find-my-tests)

do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to "(all setting except the project name are the same)." The project named MyCo.Storage.Testing had an assembly named: MyCo.Storage which then conflicted with the referenced project which generated an assembly with the same name. Changing out name of the assembly to MyCo.Storage.Testing solved the problem.